# Why does my terminal window display all these errors?

Tags: macos, mac, bash, terminal

Just recently, my terminal window has started displaying a bunch of errors at the beginning of each new session. It's almost as if it's spitting out the default text (date, etc) and interpreting it as an alias? I didn't change anything that I know of, and I've reset my computer, etc. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have a bash start script that has some currently invalid stuff in it. Check your `.bashrc`,`.bash_profile` and `.bash_login` to see if there is any offending scripting in there.

Did you recently import your account to a new/reinstalled machine or have you change the user account type for your user? Any other changes recently?

Comment: If my memory serves (I'm not near a Mac at the moment), bash on the Mac actually uses .profile for configuration

Comment: On recent OS X systems (10.4+) at least, bash "looks for ~/.bash_profile,  ~/.bash_login,  and  ~/.profile,  in that order" just like on other unix-y systems.

Comment: Yes thats the primary file. But it sill also uses `.bash_login` and i think `.bashrc` although ive never tried `.bashrc`. I mentioned all three jsut because you never know where someone might try to stick their config :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed `GhostScript` or `MacTex`? Seems like they do a set of changes to a bunch of resource files that the others are referring to.

How to fix it? Try doing below commands in the terminal to find which file might be affected

```
grep setloginpath /etc/*
grep setloginpath ~/.*
```

First line is to check the system wide configuration files for `setloginpath` and the second line to check your user account configuration files for `setloginpath`.

Hopefully you will find a file containing something in the line with

```
setloginpath added /usr/local/bin start at Sun Dec 20 01:00:21 PST 2009
```

When you found it you will have to remove the problematic line...